# How to update properties from object using input fields with onchange methods to write the data?

Tags: c#, events, blazor, onchange, syncfusion

I'm trying to make a "Edit" section to edit objects and update them in the database:

First of all I obtain the current object and load input fields depending on PropertyType(string = textfield, int = number picker, etc):

Object:

[image]

Place input fields:

```
<EditForm @ref="EditForm" Model="ObjectType" novalidate>
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
@foreach (var property in EditObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
     @if (property.PropertyType.Name.Equals("String"))
     {
           <SfTextBox Placeholder="@property.Name"
                      Type="InputType.Text"
                      @onchange="@((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs __e) => property.SetValue(EditObject, __e.Value))"
                      Value="@property.GetValue(EditObject, null)"
                      CssClass="create-model-item">
           </SfTextBox>

     }
     else if (property.PropertyType.Name.Contains("Int"))
     {
             <SfNumericTextBox TValue="int?" Placeholder="Choose a Number Value="@property.GetValue(EditObject, null)" CssClass="create-model-item">
                               <NumericTextBoxEvents TValue="int?" 
                                       ValueChange="@((Syncfusion.Blazor.Inputs.ChangeEventArgs<int?> __e) => property.SetValue(EditObject, __e.Value))">
                               </NumericTextBoxEvents>
             </SfNumericTextBox>
     }
}
<SfButton OnClick="SendForm" IsPrimary="true" CssClass="mb-3">Create</SfButton>
</EditForm>
```

Now I want to change the data of the properties in "EditObject" to the new values that the user has filled in, this is done by the "OnChange" method:

```
@onchange="@((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ChangeEventArgs __e) => property.SetValue(EditObject, __e.Value))"
```

However this is giving me this error:

[image]

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance!:)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the type of the event.

Your `@onchange` code needs to change to `@onchange="@((__e) => { property.SetValue(EditObject, __e.Value); })"`

That should stop the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a two-way binding support for Textbox component. Therefore, no additional method is needed to update new values to Model property. If you used two-way binding it will be updated by default. So, kindly try with @bind-Value attribute.

Also have a look at the below UG link.

UG link: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/textbox/data-binding/#two-way-data-binding